# How much overhead is using emulated stack in GWT?

Tags: java, performance, gwt, emulation

I'm considering using [GWT's emulated stack](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/wiki/WebModeExceptions#Emulated_Stack_Data) in web-mode and I wanted to hear, based on people's experience how much performance overhead it added?
From what I read in the above link all of the overhead is the couple of arrays and their handling as a stack which is very reasonable in my eyes.
I just want to make sure there's no cat in the bag.
Also, a reasonable increase in the size of the js files is ok by me as my users connect to very long sessions and can wait the few additional ms.

Thanks,
Ittai

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't have any data on execution speed, but Googler David Chandler stated in [this discussion](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/google-web-toolkit/r9CMWMa9NGk/discussion) that removing stack info can reduce compiled JS size by as much as 15%.

`<set-property name="compiler.stackMode" value="strip"/>`

Comment: Thanks, without any other estimates and references I guess this is the best I can get. Seeing as the size of the js files is not my biggest conecrn I think I'll stay with it.